# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

**This is the function  I am using in my model**

```
public function user_birthday() {

            $this->db->select('birth_day')
            ->from('informations')
            ->where(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('birth_day'), '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d'));
            $q = $this->db->get();
            return $q->result();
        }
```

**function in controller like `$this->data['user'] = $this->users_m->user_birthday();` that way**
**and code in the view is**

```
if (!empty($user)):
        echo $user;
    else:
        echo "No dob found";
    endif;
```

Comment: I suppose `DATE_FORMAT` and `FROM_UNIXTIME` are mysql functions, not php ones.

Comment: Which error do you retrieve?

Comment: Can you show the error. And you have to use print_r to display array.

Comment: Yes, and i am running mysql query by php. if those function are the problem then how i need to run this query?

Comment: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in. i am using print_r but  not getting  any output  @RavinderReddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those circumstances where Query Builder is more trouble that it is worth. Try this

```
$q= $this->db->query("SELECT birth_day FROM informations WHERE DATE_FORMAT(birth_day, '%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d')");

//return empty array if not records found
return $q->num_rows() > 0 ? $q->result() : [];
```

If you really, really, really want to use Query Builder then this

```
$q = $this->db
    ->select('birth_day')
    ->where("DATE_FORMAT(birth_day, '%m-%d')=", "DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%m-%d')", FALSE)
    ->get('informations');

return $q->num_rows() > 0 ? $q->result() : [];
```

Comment: why   FALSE in WHERE statement in query builder?

Comment: The FALSE prevents the statement values and identifiers from being escaped which - in this case - Codeigniter will do incorrectly.